# FFmpeg "Could not open file" error message when processing with PHP

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am using `ffmpeg` to get the image from several video files. I got my `ffmpeg` codes ready but I got the following error when I `exec` my codes.

```
ffmpeg version 0.8.6-4:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
built on Apr  2 2013 17:02:36 with gcc 4.6.3

*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
//files info...
//files info...
Incompatible pixel format 'yuv420p' for codec 'mjpeg', auto-selecting format 'yuvj420p'
//file info...
[buffer @ 0x1513c40] Buffering several frames is not supported. Please consume all available frames before adding a new one.
 Last message repeated 75 times
[image2 @ 0x1513460] Could not open file : /test/project
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Input/output error
```

I only show the error messages that have color highlighted. 
My code:

```
 $ffmpeg ="/usr/bin/ffmpeg";

 $image_source_path = '/test/project/test.mp4';
 $ALL_PLACE_WIDTH = 300;
 $ALL_PLACE_HEIGHT = 300;

 $image_cmd = " -r 1 -ss 00:00:10 -t 00:00:01 -s ".$ALL_PLACE_WIDTH."x".$ALL_PLACE_HEIGHT."   -f image2 " ;

 $dest_image_path = '/test/project';

 $str_command= $ffmpeg  ." -i " . $image_source_path . $image_cmd .$dest_image_path;
 shell_exec($str_command);
```

It seems my Linux wants to me to switch to `avconv`. I am not sure how to fix these errors. Can someone give me a hint about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should always show the **full** output and not cut out parts. In your example, the error would have been more apparent if you showed the actual `ffmpeg` command line that was executed instead of the whole PHP code around it.

In your case, your problem is that the command looks like:

```
ffmpeg -i /test/project/test.mp4 -r 1 -ss 00:00:10 -t 00:00:01 -f image2 /test/project
```

However, `/test/project` is a folder, and not a valid output image path. You can use `/text/project/image%04d.jpg` if you want images being created from `image0001.jpg` onwards.

If you real goal is to just export one thumbnail, use the `vframes` option:

```
ffmpeg -i /test/project/test.mp4 -r 1 -ss 00:00:10 -vframes 1 /test/project/image.jpg
```

In newer `ffmpeg`, you can use `-frames:v` as well.

---

You can use the `ffmpeg` in Ubuntu, but it's an old version. You can either use `avconv` from [Libav](http://libav.org/) or the original `ffmpeg` from [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) — I would recommend [compiling it from source](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide).

Answer (score 2):

I encounter the same problem, and in my case I had wrong filename (for example 00:00:00.png) so its basically a OS limitation not ffmpeg's
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the problems I’m seeing with these issues is due to wrong filename.  Perhaps you formatted it wrong.  Sliced it wrong or modified it is some manner that makes it an invalid path.